# The [filter] tag is ambiguous

Tags: discussion, status-completed, retag-request, tags, tag-cleanup-request

See [list of questions tagged `filter`](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/filter): some of them are about ffmpeg filters (used for resizing videos and such), some are about filtering data in MS Excel, some are about organising emails... none of these things are the same, or similar enough to be covered by the same tag..

Maybe it should be split up into more specific tags. 'ffmpeg-filters' could certainly be useful, for example (I think this is the most glaring problem, since at least the others are about sorting data).

Comment: [Related](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125234/a-real-solution-to-ambiguous-tags)... How long before we get the `filter` tag again after we split it up?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Split the tag to:

- for various media: [audio-filter](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/audio-filter), [image-filter](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/image-filter), [video-filter](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/video-filter)
- [ffmpeg-filter](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/ffmpeg-filter) (make synonym of [video-filter](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/video-filter))
- [email-filter](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/email-filter)
- [internet-filter](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/internet-filter)
- [file-filter](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/file-filter) (can also be used for *some* questions tagged with [search](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/search) and [file](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/file)/[folder](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/folder))

Remove the tag for other cases, since they don't appear to be significant enough to justify their own tags.

Comment: I've added some more tags I think are useful, after noticing a good amount of them in the [tag:filter] tag.  In regards to the [tag:internet-filter], do you think it would be worth-while to make the tags [tag:network-filter] and [tag:web-filter] synonyms thereof?

Comment: I would think so. They mean practically the same thing. While there are different types of network filters, I don't think extra tags are justified here.

Answer (score 0):

This is completed. At least, until someone recreates the tag.