# Filter the [filter] tag

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tag-cleanup-request

Well, another useless meta tag - [filter](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/filter) has a useless Tag Wiki and Tag Wiki Exert, and does not enhance any of the questions tagged with it. There was [another request](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/6691/the-filter-tag-is-ambiguous) already to kill it, but it looks like it either came back, or was never dealt with before.

Let's filter it out properly... With a mixture of gasoline, oxygen, and high, high hot temperatures :)

Comment: Given that the old question already scored high enough, I marked this planned right away.